# Possible to self refence element inside style={}? - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

is it possible to reference the button itself when declaring the style? `style={this.current.disabled == true ? {...`

```
                            <button
                                ref={createRef}
                                type='submit'
                                disabled={name === '' || category === '' || institute === '' || description === ''}
                                style={this.current.disabled == true ? { color: "red" } : { color: "yellow" }}
                                onClick={() => createChat()}
                            >Create</button>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work, ie:

```
const disabled = name === '' || category === '' || institute === '' || description === '';

const buttonStyles = { color: "yellow" };
const disabledStyles = { color: "red" }; 

return <button
  disabled={disabled}
  style={{ ...buttonStyles, ...(disabled && disabledStyles) }}
>
  Create
<button>
```

however, you cannot access `this` or the underlying element - React function components do not have `this`, and its value will be undefined.

You *could* use the `ref.current?.disabled`, but it would be undefined on the first run, and is not recommended.

It would be best performance-wise to use regular css or some full css-in-js solution, because you will be able to access the `:disabled { }` pseudo selector, like so:

```css
.my-button {
  color: 'yellow';
}

.my-button:disabled {
  color: 'red';
}
```

Comment: Works great. Can you explain the logic in the style? What does `...` and `,` mean in this context?

Comment: it's the "spread" operator - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but you have to use like this

```
 <button 
   ref={createRef} 
   type='submit'
   disabled={name === '' || category === '' || institute === '' || 
    description === ''}
   style={{ color: this.current.disabled == true ? "red" : "yellow" }}
   onClick={() => createChat()}
 >Create</button>
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current'). Tbh, I'm not even even sure how to access the disabled attribute.